# Intuitionistic derivation of ~~~A --> ~A

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I need to give an intuitionistic derivation of ~~~A --> ~A by using natural deduction. I know that in intuitionistic terms ~~~A --> ~A converts to ~~~A → ~A i.e ⊦ ((A → ⊥)→ ⊥→ ⊥) → (A → ⊥).

These are the steps I took so far:

```
                                         [A→ ⊥]1 [A]
                                        ____________ (→Elim)
                                             ⊥
                                 1_______________________  ( → Intro)
                                [(A→ ⊥) → ⊥]     [A → ⊥]2
                      _________________________________________________  ( → Elim)
                                              ⊥
                  2  ___________________________________________________ ( → Intro)
                                     [(A→ ⊥) → ⊥ → ⊥]
                    _____________________________________________________ ( → Intro)



               ________________________________________________________________
                                        [A → ⊥]
               _________________________________________________________________ ( → Intro)
                                 ((A → ⊥)→ ⊥→ ⊥) → (A → ⊥)
```

I'm not sure if I am on the right track. I'm sure I'm missing some things.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand the derivation above.... You have to start with  **(((A → ⊥)→ ⊥)→ ⊥)** and derive **(A → ⊥)**.

Comment: To do this, assume **A**, introduce Double Negation, that is intuitionistically valid, and you have a contradiction. Thus, you can discharge the assumption **A** by →-Intro deriving **(A → ⊥)**.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  But the fact you can inject double negation is what he is being asked to prove (or at least he is being asked to prove one half of it).  No?  So this would be circular.

Comment: Suppose `A` as a premise. Assume `A→⊥`. Derive `⊥` by → E. Derive `(A→⊥)→⊥` by →I, discharging the assumption.  Therefore `A` entails  `(A→⊥)→⊥`.  @hide_in_plain_sight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a Fitch style proof.

```
1.|  |_ ~~~A       H      
2.|  |  |_ A       H
3.|  |  |  |_ ~A   H
4.|  |  |  |  ⊥    ~E 2,3
5.|  |  |  ~~A     ~I 3-4
6.|  |  |  ⊥       ~E 5,1
7.|  |  ~A         ~I 2-6
8.|  ~~~A → ~A     →I 1-7
```

As you know, the rule of ~I is basically →I when negation is defined as `~A` = `A→⊥`

Likewise ~E is →E, since `A` and `A→⊥` entails `⊥` by modus ponens.

Thus the Fitch proof can be expressed as:

```
1.|  |_ ((A→⊥)→⊥)→⊥        H      
2.|  |  |_ A               H
3.|  |  |  |_ A→⊥          H
4.|  |  |  |  ⊥            →E 2,3
5.|  |  |  (A→⊥)→⊥         →I 3-4
6.|  |  |  ⊥               →E 5,1
7.|  |  A→⊥                →I 2-6
8.|  (((A→⊥)→⊥)→⊥)→(A→⊥)  →I 1-7
```

So convert to the tree by:

- Assume `A→⊥` and `A`
- Derive `⊥` with →E.
- Derive `(A→⊥)→⊥` with →I, discharging `A→⊥`
- Assume `((A→⊥)→⊥)→⊥`
- Derive `⊥` with →E.
- Derive `A→⊥` with →I, discharging `A`
- Derive `(((A→⊥)→⊥)→⊥)→(A→⊥)` with →I, discharging `((A→⊥)→⊥)→⊥`